# I have a problem while trying to use forEach

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying, when someone writes a message in guild A/B/C, the bot who is in for example 3 servers, to send me the message in the 4th server, sending them in different text channels named "guild A", "guild B" and " guild C ", not in the same ones...

I get the following error:

```
channel.send(msgLog)

TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
```

And this is my code:

````
const msgLog = `[#${message.channel.name}]=[${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}]=> ${message.content}` ```

client.guilds.cache.map(guild => server.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name == guild.name)).forEach(channel => 
      channel.send(msgLog)
      );
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that `channel` is `undefined`, and you cannot any property (such as `'send'`) of `undefined`.

This means that `server` does not have a channel with the name `guild.name` for some guilds.

You could use `filter` to only include channels that are defined:

```js
client.guilds.cache
  .map(guild => server.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name == guild.name))
  .filter(channel => channel) // returns false if channel === undefined
  .forEach(channel => channel.send(msgLog));
```

This is roughly equivalent to

```js
client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
  const channel = server.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name == guild.name));
  if (channel) {
    channel.send(msgLog);
  }
});
```